# how to parse xml file having <map-Map><map-Entry><map-Key><map-Value> in java

Tags: java, xml

i have xml file having

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
               <soapenv:Body>
                  <getiResponse xmlns="http://ofbiz.apache.org/service/">
        <map-Map>
                                <map-Entry>
                                   <map-Key>
                                      <std-String value="asd"/>
                                   </map-Key>
                                   <map-Value>
                                      <std-String value="123"/>
                                   </map-Value>
                                </map-Entry>
```

i want parse in java.please give suggestions

Comment: but i did not get values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter [your question without the xml tags in Google](https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+parse+xml+file+in+java&safe=active), you find enough information on the first page.

I propose to check out the [JAXP trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html) of the [Oracle Java SE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), which shows you how to do it the standard Java way.

And then, as your XML example suggests, if you want to parse SOAP envelopes, you are in the field of [JAX-WS web services](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxws.htm#BNAYL), which you can learn more about in the [Oracle Java EE tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend dom4j, I've used it in the past and it works fine.

[dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/)